# simple IPC mechanism for C#/WPF application to implement app CLI

Tags: .net, remoting, ipc, named-pipes

So I've been reading lots about interprocess communication on .Net. Named pipes, remoting. It all seems great but possibly overkill for what I need to do.

I want to add a command line interface to my WPF application, so I need a simple IPC mechanism to send the string from one process to the already running app.

What does SO recommend for doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NamedPipeClientStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream.aspx) and [NamedPipeServerStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream.aspx) are pretty simple.  [Here's a pretty simple example](http://web.archive.org/web/20080516173418/http://www.flawlesscode.com/post/2008/02/Enforcing-single-instance-with-argument-passing.aspx) where IPC is used to pass command line arguments from one instance of an application to another.  It's not exactly what you want to do, but pretty close.

Comment: great little article about NamedPipes. Thanks bizzaro JP! (I'm JP too).

Comment: WebArchive for the link that has since died: http://web.archive.org/web/20080506103924/http://www.flawlesscode.com/post/2008/02/Enforcing-single-instance-with-argument-passing.aspx